# How can I calculate the number of lines changed between two versions in Git?

Tags: git, git-diff

Is there any way to calculate the number of lines changed between two versions in Git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view the number of insertions and deletions made in each commit using:

```
$ git log --stat
```

For the changes between any two specific commits, you may use:

```
$ git diff --stat <commit-id1> <commit-id2>
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Have you any idea for the changes between two specific versions or tags?

Comment: You can get the commit to which a tag points by using ```$ git rev-list -n 1 $TAG```. Then you could follow the above procedure

Comment: Or simply `git diff --stat tag1 tag2`, there's no need to run `rev-list -n1 tag1` (or rather `rev-parse tag1`) first